# How to enumerate package dependencies in a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Guys i've been coding an node_module that's gives you the dependencies of the module you choose, So there is my code

```
function depend(modulename, cb) {
let package = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./node_modules/"+modulename+'/package.json', "utf8"));
var re = 'CHECKING' ? package.dependencies : 'The module has no dependencies';
cb(re)  
}

const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = depend;
```

When i run it it on a module has no modules its gives me `{}` Instead of `The module has no dependencies`, So any ideas?

Comment: What does `var re = 'CHECKING' ?` means to you ?

Comment: UHM, I had an other example 
`function depend(modulename, cb) {
 let package = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./node_modules/"+modulename+'/package.json', "utf8"));
 if(package.dependencies){
  cb(package.dependencies);
 } else {
  cb('The module has no modules');
 }
}

const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = depend;`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at how the [Ternary (conditional) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) works.

In reference to the code you posted a comment:

Your current code simply checks for the existence of package.dependencies, which even if it is an empty object, something like `if(package.dependencies)...` will evaluate to true because an empty object is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value.

What you need to do is check if the object itself is empty. One way to do that is to check the length of its keys by using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

`var re = Object.keys(package.dependencies).length ? package.dependencies : 'The module has no dependencies';`

But an even better check would be a combination of your approach and this one:

`var re = package.dependencies && Object.keys(package.dependencies).length ? ...`

As it checks for both the existence of package.dependencies as well as whether or not it is empty.

Comment: Remember that there may not be a dependancies property at all.

Answer (score 1):

`var re = 'CHECKING' ? package.dependencies : 'The module has no dependencies';` is a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Here it means :

> If 'CHECKING' then assign `package.dependencies` to `re` otherwise assign `'The module has no dependencies'` to `re`

This is your error, `if ('CHECKING')` will always evaluate to `true` so it will always assign `package.dependencies` to `re`. You'll have to refactor your code to something like this :

```
var re = Object.keys(package.dependencies).length > 0 ? package.dependencies : 'The module has no dependencies';
```

Which will test if `package.dependencies` have one or more dependencies in order to affect the correct value to `re`. We don't use `length` on `package.dependencies` because it is an object which haven't any `length` property, instead we use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

In the second example you provided in the comments, `if (package.dependencies)` will also always evaluate to `true` because `package.dependencies` is not null or undefined, so it's considered to be `true`.

Comment: Thanks for all your support! <3